# IS it ok for react (no flux, redux etc) to have subcomponents with state or should the root component store state

Tags: reactjs, state

I keep reading that in react (I'm just using react to create a test application to see how react works) state should be stored in the root component and when state changes the whole tree should be re-rendered.

Currently I have created a bootstrap navigation bar.

```
root
--> NavBar
    --> NavHeader
    --> NavMenuBar
        --> NavMenuItem
            ...
--> PageContent
--> Footer
```

I store the active menu item in my NavMenuBar component. Then when a menu item or one of the subs is clicked a callback is used to update the state in the NavMenuBar and react re-renders the changed menu items.

This is working fine, but now I'm wondering if I should be storing the active menu item in the NavMenuBar component. Should I instead store the state in the root component and move the callback method to update the menu state there too? I don't see why the root app needs to keep track of the active menu item but lots of bloggers/articles suggest I should be using the root component for all state, but on this FB page:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

under "Step 4: Identify Where Your State Should" they say you should find a common parent to store state and don't mention storing everything in root.

*PS: I know there is a NPM component for rendering a BS nav bar but I'm doing this myself to learn more about react.*

Answer (score 2):

Storing all states *in root component only* is totally **not a good way**!

The reason is (you already knew and stated this ^^): when that root component updates (I mean re-render,) all its children, grandchildren as well as all other great-grandchildren will be unnecessarily updated, too. We only need to update the necessary child-components, which means:

=> [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html - "Step 4: Identify Where Your State Should" they say you should find **a common parent** to store state] *is correct*

Therefore, in your case, storing the active menu item in your NavMenuBar component is *a good way*.

Actually, the "*active*" will be applied on your NavMenuItem, and the "*common*" parent for all NavMenuItems is certainly the NavMenuBar.

By this way, when the active menu item changes, the NavMenuBar will update itself, and re-render all its children (NavMenuItems, the last-active item will return to normal, the new active one will be active ^^, other menu-items will not be re-rendered [because there's no change for those other items, you can read more about React's Virtual DOM, but that's another story ^^, here is just 1 article about this, you can surely find a lot more: https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/the-real-benefits-of-the-virtual-dom-in-react-js/]

Answer (score 2):

Which component store data in state and which doesn't is completely your choice.

There are mainly two type of components, one that have data and other that doesn't. This comes with many names and slight differences with pros and cons.

https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

People recommend solutions against some recurring problems. If you don't have problem then you will never need  the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest highlighting the active menu item does not influence the application very much, so I'd stick with having it in the child component, because propagating the stage through all those components only creates unnecessary boilerplate code.